# Show all the groupped value that have same value more than 1

Tags: mysql, group-by, having

I have table like this

```
table1

| ID  |  Val |  Val2  |
|  2  |  AA  |   0    |
|  3  |  AA  |   1    |
|  4  |  AD  |   0    |
|  5  |  CV  |   1    |
|  6  |  AF  |   1    |
|  7  |  CV  |   1    |
```

I want to know if there is duplicate value in column `Val` more than one. I used the `group by` clause. plus i want to know how many duplicate appear in `Val`

```
select Val,count(Val) from table 
group by Val where 
having count(val) > 1
```

result :

```
| Val | count(val) |
| AA  |   2        | 
| CV  |   2        |
```

Now i want to know which column that have duplicate value so i used Group_concat with query like this

```
select Val,count(Val), group_concat(ID) from table1 
group by Val where 
having count(val) > 1
```

Results

```
| Val | count(val) | group_concat(ID) |
| AA  |   2        |  2,3             |
| CV  |   2        |  5,7             |
```

Now i dont know how to show all the duplicate value, i only show which id that had duplicate value by group_concat() but i couldn't show all data without the `group_concat` column. I tried to use `Field_in_set` but it seems not working.

```
select Val,count(Val), group_concat(ID) from table1 
where FIELD_IN_SET(ID,group_concat(ID))
group by Val where 
having count(val) > 1
```

What i expect is i want to show all the duplicate value after i `group by` and `count` the value like below table

```
| ID  |  Val |  Val2  |
|  2  |  AA  |   0    |
|  3  |  AA  |   1    |
|  5  |  CV  |   1    |
|  7  |  CV  |   1    |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table1 (
>   `ID` INTEGER,
>   `Val` VARCHAR(2),
>   `Val2` INTEGER
> );
>
> INSERT INTO table1
>   (`ID`, `Val`, `Val2`)
> VALUES
>   ('2', 'AA', '0'),
>   ('3', 'AA', '1'),
>   ('4', 'AD', '0'),
>   ('5', 'CV', '1'),
>   ('6', 'AF', '1'),
>   ('7', 'CV', '1');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT  t1.* 
> FROM table1 t1 
>   INNER JOIN (SELECT COUNT(`Val`) countval, `Val`  FROM table1 GROUP BY `Val`) t2 
>     ON t1.`Val` = t2.`Val`
> WHERE countval > 1
> ```
>
> ```
> ID | Val | Val2
> -: | :-- | ---:
>  2 | AA  |    0
>  3 | AA  |    1
>  5 | CV  |    1
>  7 | CV  |    1
> ```

> ```
> SELECT `ID`, `Val`, `Val2`     
> FROM ( SELECT
>          `ID`, `Val`, `Val2`,
>          COUNT(`Val`) OVER(PARTITION BY `Val`) c1
>        FROM table1) t1
>    WHERE c1 > 1
> ```
>
> ```
> ID | Val | Val2
> -: | :-- | ---:
>  2 | AA  |    0
>  3 | AA  |    1
>  5 | CV  |    1
>  7 | CV  |    1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=046ac3c24792409e37caac048f7b4d53)*

Comment: i got an error `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '( PARTITION BY `NIK` ) c1 FROM bansos_tahap4_wilayah_tanpa_ber_iris_ojol_vp ) t1' at line 4`

Comment: the second code works only in mysql 8  i put both there, today it os hard to tell which version ypu have

Comment: ohh i see, i used mysql 5.7. Thanks a lot, well loks like i could only used the first one

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return the rows with the duplicate `Val`s then use `EXISTS`:

```
select t.* from tablename t 
where exists (select 1 from tablename where Val = t.Val and ID <> t.ID)
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/YFxY9ccGG6q4MJbwUAp5L/0).
Results:

```
| ID  | Val | Val2 |
| --- | --- | ---- |
| 2   | AA  | 0    |
| 3   | AA  | 1    |
| 5   | CV  | 1    |
| 7   | CV  | 1    |
```

Comment: what  if i want the duplicate value is more than 2 ? how could i do that ?

Comment: `select t.* from tablename t where t.Val in (select Val from tablename group by Val having count(*) > 2)`